# Hyphen point list WriteLatex

Tags: overleaf

I'm should have a hyphen point list in write latex is looking like below

Inn:    - person

```
    - User

    - Adresse
```

How can I making this in WriteLatex?

Comment: As requested in response to your other question (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171352/39222), please post the code for a complete small document demonstrating the issue. I hope that this will help me to understand your question. I'm afraid that I do not understand what you are asking right now.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{\widthof{In:}}
\begin{document}
  In: \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\mylen-\leftmargin\relax}
  \begin{itemize}
    \renewcommand\labelitemi{--}
    \item Inn
    \item User
    \item Adresse
  \end{itemize}%
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]